# Is text-bot.mybluemix.net app still using the Insights for Weather APIs?

Tags: node.js, weather-api, watson-conversation

I went over IBM bot - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-bot, this bot is working at this address: https://text-bot.mybluemix.net ;

### # the following instruction is provided here: https://github.com/eGlobeBizCom/text-bot

Edit the manifest.yml file in the folder that contains your clone of the repository and replace application-name with a unique name for your copy of the application. The name that you specify determines the application's URL, such as application-name.mybluemix.net. The relevant portion of the manifest.yml file looks like the following:

declared-services:
 conversation-service:
   label: conversation
   plan: free
 weatherinsights-service:
   label: weatherinsights
   plan: Free-v2
 cloudantNoSQLDB-service:
   label: cloudantNoSQLDB
   plan: Lite
 applications:
   - services:
     - conversation-service
     - weatherinsights-service
     - cloudantNoSQLDB-service
   name: weather-conversation-bot
   command: npm start
   path: .

### memory: 512M

## About "weatherinsights-service"

Based on this page: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/InsightsWeather/weather_overview.html#pricing_models
This service is deprecated: All instances of this service are deprecated.

## I guess that, the js code on the above github page should not work based on the deprecated APIs . But this bot https://text-bot.mybluemix.net  is still working now. So, I guess that the real code in this bot should call another weather API and not the above weather API.

Wish to hear any input from those who have some info about the above weather bot. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Insights for Weather API service has been deprecated as you stated correctly. Cloud Foundry/Bluemix uses a service name and plan to locate and use services within the environment and not the Name that may appear in the Bluemix GUI.

The service that replaced the Insights for Weather APIs was the Weather Company Data service. This service has that same service name and plan as the previous service. Thus, the sample application above will continue to work. You can always find the service name for the manifest.yml by invoking the following command:

```
cf marketplace
```

Note the screenshot below:

Name__________________Service__________Plan
[image]